# MySql/PHP Forum Problems With Selecting Forum To View

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

i have 2 files fourm.php and viewfourm.php

fourm.php first

```
<?php

$host="mysql13.000webhost.com"; // Host name 
$username="a2670376_Users"; // Mysql username 
$password="PASS"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="a2670376_Pass"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="fourm"; // Table name 

  // Connect to server and select database.
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

  // select record from mysql 
  $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
 ?>
<table>
<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Post Number</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>UserName</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Topic</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Date</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>View</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td><? echo $rows['fourmid']; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td><? echo $rows['username']; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td><? echo $rows['fourmname']; ?   >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td><? echo $rows['date']; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td><a href="viewfourm.php?id=<? echo $rows['fourmid']; ?>">View Topic</a></td>
<?php
 // close while loop 
 }
 ?>

</tr>
</table>
<?php
// close connection; 
mysql_close();
?>
<hr width='67%' color='#29001F' size='3'/>
</center>
```

now viewfourm.php

```
 <?php

 $host="mysql13.000webhost.com"; // Host name 
 $username="a2670376_Users"; // Mysql username 
 $password="PASS"; // Mysql password 
 $db_name="a2670376_Pass"; // Database name 
 $tbl_name="fourm"; // Table name 

   // Connect to server and select database.
   mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
   mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    // select record from mysql 
   $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
   $result=mysql_query($sql);
   ?>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td align="center"><strong>Post Number</strong></td>
 <td align="center"><strong>UserName</strong></td>
 <td align="center"><strong>Topic</strong></td>
 <td align="center"><strong>Date</strong></td>
 <td align="center"><strong>View</strong></td>
 </tr>
 <?php
 while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 ?>
 <tr>
 <td><? echo $rows['fourmid']; ? >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
 <td><? echo $rows['username']; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td><? echo $rows['fourmname']; ?   >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td><? echo $rows['date']; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td><a href="fourm.php">back/a></td>
<?php
 // close while loop 
 }
 ?>

</tr>
</table>
<?php
// close connection; 
mysql_close();
?>
<hr width='67%' color='#29001F' size='3'/>
</center>
```

now on forum.php when i select what "forum" from MySql Database i want to view it loads all the forums i want to fix i know why its doing it its cause its the same script as the first one just modified a little bit but i did what i could do. i am selecting forum s thrue fourmid tag in MySql Database thats what the ">View Topic is about its supposed to load the forum with the id selected

Comment: sql vurnurable i know ill fix it later once i fix this

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: MySQLi im still learning MySql and php lol ill learn that next but to me MySQL is easier

Comment: Also don't use spaces for alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In viewfourm.php modify your sql query `$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";` like this

`$fourmid= $_POST['fourmid'];  //if passing using get method use $_GET['fourmid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE`fourmid`= '$fourmid'";`

Also you have to pass fourmid from fourm.php to viewfourm.php

**EDIT**

Make a link like this

`<td>
<a href="viewfourm.php?fourmid=<? echo $rows['fourmid']; ?>">
<? echo $rows['fourmname']; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</a>
</td>`

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a2670376/public_html/fourms/viewfourm.php on line 35
 i got this and i did this to the script// select record from mysql 
$fourmid= $_POST['fourmid']; 
//if passing using get method use $_GET['fourmid'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHEREfourmid= '$fourmid'";

Comment: make a link in fourm.php for each topic

Comment: still isnt working ither im not understanding what you mean or it wont work

Answer (score 0):

in form.php get the value from

```
a href="viewfourm.php?id=<? echo $rows['fourmid']; ?>">View Topic</a>
```

//viewform.php

$fourmid= $_REQUEST['**id**'];.

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE fourmid= '$fourmid'";

Try it..

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a2670376/public_html/fourms/viewfourm.php on line 34